# MegaRAID: New SSDs blink red

Tags: windows-server-2016, ssd, megaraid, storcli

Last week I installed two new SSDs for a customer. It's an Server 2016 Standard Core with Intel Xeon @ 3.70 GHz, 4x32GB RAM and LSI RAID-Controller 9341-8i.

I created a RAID 1 with 2x1TB SSDs via StorCLI and all works fine. Consistency = ok, Initialization = OK. I also can use it in Windows correctly.

But when I take a look on the physical machine, both disks blink red.

Here's the storcli output for VDs:

[image: VD output]

Do anyone have any idea why both disks blink red? The controller health is fine. Same as VD and physical disk health.

Comment: Have you looked at the manual of the SSDs, maybe it is a normal behaviour? Can you give us the model and vendor of the SSDs?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have solved the problem: I put the parameter "Strip=64" in my command to create the virtual drive. After I deleted the VD and recreated it without the parameter, it works fine.